# C# application Manifest ignored / not working

Tags: c#, manifest, x86-64, windows-7-x64, administrator

When I was trying to create a custom setup application in C# I needed the requireAdministrator privilege.

I need the requireAministrator privilege to prevend the "This program might not have installed correctly" message.

Normally this is done by adding the following line to your application manifest as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598824/how-to-force-my-c-sharp-winforms-program-run-as-administrator-on-any-computer).

But the problem was not solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After hours of searching I found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowscompatibility/thread/fcebe7a4-2841-4898-9621-2e638de83fa6).

In short:
Application Manifest may be ignored in Windows 7 x64 when building a x86 application.

When I changed my Platform target to x64 the Manifest was not longer ignored.
And my problem was solved.