# How to force my project in Visual Studio 2013 to always run as Administrator?

Tags: c#, wpf, service, visual-studio-2013, elevated-privileges

I have a WPF project in Visual Studio 2013, this project have two buttons. The first button say Start Service and the second say Stop Service.
When I run my Visual Studio as Administrator, the buttons work. But when I open my Visual Studio without privilages, the InvalidOperationException exception appear.

How to force my project start with privilages when Visual Studio doesn't run as  administrator?

I added app.manifest  to my project and change  for

level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>

but it didn't function.

For start or stop my service, I am using ServiceController.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to force my C# Winforms program run as administrator on any computer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598824/how-to-force-my-c-sharp-winforms-program-run-as-administrator-on-any-computer)

Comment: This solution does not functioned for my.

Comment: Your comment does not functioned your problem.

Comment: The WPF application use a method in WCFService for stop or start service...
This have some implication?

Comment: do you want to debug as admin?

Comment: I want my project always start with privileges although Visual Studio doesn't start with privileges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is interesting and it seems you need to change permissions of how the project runs, Try doing the following

- go to project properties > Security
- enable click-once security settings and select Full trust application

More infor in this link
[WPF security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970910%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 8):

As Torben M. Philippsen mentions in his [article](http://philippsen.wordpress.com/tag/requestedexecutionlevel-manifest/):

- In Visual Studio 2010 (I guess the same applies to VS2008, but I
  haven’t tested it) right click Your project and select “add new item”
- Add a application manifest file – the default name will be app.manifest.
- Inside the manifest file, change the existing configuration from

  ```
  <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
  ```

  To

  ```
  <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
  ```
- Save and close the manifest file.
- Please note that Your manifest file won’t show up anywhere in your solution. In order to fix that, in solution explorer, click the “show all files” button.
- Important: Right click the manifest file and add it to the project – we need that in order to tell VS to use the manifest file when compiling our application.
- Right click Your project and select “properties”.
- On the application tab, the bottom section, select the manifest file:

[image: Selecting manifest file]

manifest file selection

- Compile and run the application. If Your UAC settings are enabled, You will be prompted to allow the application to start in elevated mode.
- Sometimes it can come in handy to check whether Your application is actually running in elevated mode or not. Maybe You will find this codesnippet usefull:

  ```
   WindowsPrincipal myPrincipal = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
   if (myPrincipal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator) == false )
   {
       //show messagebox - displaying a messange to the user that rights are missing
       MessageBox.Show("You need to run the application using the \"run as administrator\" option", "administrator right required", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation); 
   }
   else
   {
       MessageBox.Show("You are good to go - application running in elevated mode", "Good job" ,MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
   }
  ```