# Powershell script but not making the changes required in registry

Tags: c#, powershell

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"c:\temp";
        processStartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        // set additional properties     
        Process proc = Process.Start(processStartInfo);

        //process.StandardInput.WriteLine("c:");
        proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass c:\\temp\\autologin.ps1");
        proc.StandardInput.Close();
```

Powershell

```
$RegPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon"  
Set-ItemProperty $RegPath "AutoAdminLogon" -Value "0" -type String  
Set-ItemProperty $RegPath "DefaultUsername" -Value " " -type String  
Set-ItemProperty $RegPath "DefaultPassword" -Value " " -type String
```

I've been trying to run a powershell script that my program writes. I can't just run the powershell commands in the program because I will be rebooting the computers and accessing that powershell program again.

Any ideas? Currently it will run the commands but not make the changes to the registry but if i enter the commands myself into CMD it works perfectly. So I'm a little stuck the only thing I need is for C# to run that powershell script for me.

`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` reg keys for reference

**NEW EDIT:** program is executing but putting the registry keys in WOW6432Node

Comment: What registry keys are you modifying?  Do they require admin rights to access them?

Comment: proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("reg add " + c + "HKLM\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon" + c + " /v AutoAdminLogon /t REG_SZ /d 0 /f");
            proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("reg add " + c + "HKLM\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon" + c + " /v DefaultUserName /t REG_SZ /d " + username + " /f");
            proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("reg add " + c + "HKLM\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon" + c + " /v DefaultPassword /t REG_SZ /d " + "yes" + " /f");
            proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("Timeout 10");

Comment: Thats the Batch version of it the powershell version is different however I just changed the way i wrote it to not be running the script but instead running the commands seperatly and i get success however still no changes to the registry.

Comment: Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon reg keys for reference

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow.  You could do your readers a favour by updating your post to include information about the keys you are trying to change.  Perhaps even include a copy of your script (or better yet a shorter test script that reproduces your problem and only affects one registry key).  Yes they can read these comments for themselves, but why make them work harder than necessary?  See [ask] and [mcve] for more helpful hints on how to ask good questions.

Comment: I don't believe it is a firewall issue, unless you are attempting to execute the commands on a remote machine.

Have you confirmed that the script is executing?  It doesn't look like it is outputing any trace messages.

Comment: Yes it is executing actually the issue lies in the fact its running in 64 bit mode and its putting the registry keys in WOW6432Node of the registry

Answer (score 1):

```
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v AutoAdminLogon /t REG_SZ /d 0 /reg:64 /f
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultUserName /t REG_SZ /d USERNAME /reg:64 /f
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultPassword /t REG_SZ /d PASSWORD /reg:64 /f
```

went with a batch solution after debugging found i could just edit the way i wrote the file. Now it runs perfectly thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the issue is that your application needs admin rights to access those keys.  With Windows 7 and newer and UAC enabled, even if the logged in user has admin rights, the processes will not have admin rights unless they request it.

This article: [How to force my C# Winforms program run as administrator on any computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598824/how-to-force-my-c-sharp-winforms-program-run-as-administrator-on-any-computer)

Should help you setup your project so that it runs with admin rights.

Comment: Sadly I have already made the changes to the app manifest to <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" /> and the problem isn't CMD not running as admin i Debugged it running as admin and actually wrote my commands into the CMD propt it opened and they ran fine. However my program is on my E: drive and not my main C: i moved it and still same results.

Answer (score 0):

You should to build your application on X64 platform target and then run with  admin rights. [refer to this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ns6lU.jpg)