# Read From Protected Path Permission Denied

Tags: c#

I would like to read from the Drive C: to search for a file in subfolders for my file search program everything works fine when I test this program in Visual studio but when I publish the project and my program try to read from the Drive it throw the Permission exception please tell me how to solve this I have tried code on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermission(v=vs.110).aspx) but no luck also I am not able to run file as administrator with no error.
Here is my code.

```
            try
            {
                FileIOPermission f2 = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, Path.Text);
                f2.Demand();
                AddDir(Directory.GetDirectories(Path.Text));

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

               MessageBox.Show($"Sorry we cannot read directories from {Path} because {e.ToString()}");
                Startthread.Abort();

            }
```

**Exception**

[image]

Comment: Try running it as Administrator

Comment: File not running as admin.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598824/how-to-force-my-c-sharp-winforms-program-run-as-administrator-on-any-computer